# Can't insert a value into the table. PyQGIS 3.0. Postgresql

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, database

Can't insert a value into the table. PyQGIS 3.0

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='postgres', password='1', host='localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO table_name (name, make, model, year)
                    VALUES('Alex', 'Toyota', 'Supra', '2017-10-12');
                """)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I run the code, but nothing data is added.
[image]

Comment: There is no GIS component to this question. There are a number of seriously wrong issues in this question -- You should never connect as the postgres user; you should never use a trivial password (or even include one in an Internet post),...

Comment: ...never use the 'postgres' maintenance DB to store data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: I'd like to stress out the security issues inherent in your code, as pointed out in the comments to the question!*

In general, the connection needs a *commit* to make the DB transaction take effect. You can either call

```
conn.commit()
```

after each transaction execution (or, before you close the cursor/connection), or set the execution of transactions to *autocommit* when opening the connection

```
conn.autocommit = True
```

In your code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='postgres', user='postgres', password='1', host='localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO table_name (name, make, model, year) VALUES('Alex', 'Toyota', 'Supra', '2017-10-12'); """)

conn.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```